# What is the precedence order of the `LS_COLORS` environment variable?

Tags: ls

I'm aware GNU `ls --color` uses the `LS_COLORS` environment variable, but if a file satisfies two different conditions, which color is used?

Just as an example, directories are executable, but they don't appear green---why is that?

Answer (score 1):

**It takes the last one given.**

For example the color for .tar files is red and shows up like this when you **`echo $LS_COLORS`**

```
*.tar=01;31:
```

If I append that to end of the variable, but this time changing it to purple by doing the command below, purple shows up as the color for files with the .tar extension:

```
LS_COLORS="${LS_COLORS}*.tar=01;35:"
```

Be sure to export the variable if you need it exported.

---

Regarding the other part of your question, `di` is for directory and `0;32` is green. The default for directories that I've seen is `di=01;34:`, which is blue

You can get what the colors mean from here: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html

```
Black       0;30     Dark Gray     1;30
Blue        0;34     Light Blue    1;34
Green       0;32     Light Green   1;32
Cyan        0;36     Light Cyan    1;36
Red         0;31     Light Red     1;31
Purple      0;35     Light Purple  1;35
Brown       0;33     Yellow        1;33
Light Gray  0;37     White         1;37
```

Comment: Well, you definitely need to have `LS_COLORS` exported, otherwise `ls` is never going to see it.

Comment: Yes, but executables are green and directories have their execute bit set. ex appears after di in the listing